# Sugarcrm 8.0 custom module with rest api

Tags: sugarcrm

Hello guys im new to sugarcrm how do i create a custom module with an api in it, from scratch?

im having trouble finding good reference with easy to follow instructions.

Any example will do. Thanks in advance to the genius devs out there.

Comment: What do you mean with "by scratch"? Sugar 8 has a "Module Builder" in the admin area that can create custom modules. Do you need a custom API or just the "usual" API for listing/creating/reading/updating/deleting records? If you don't need any special API, then you're already set, as Sugar offers the list/C/R/U/D APIs across all modules automatically (look at page `/rest/v11_1/help` of your sugar instance, the `<module>` placeholder will be e.g. the name of your custom module). It actually has to do so, because the Sugar 8 UI in the browser utilizes each module's REST API to load/write data :)

Comment: Thanks man for the advice ive already build my custom module and api with unique functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these links should help:

Information about the REST API:
https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_8.2/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/

How to create custom endpoints: 
https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_8.2/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/Extending_Endpoints/

Also, I would recommend asking your questions in the SugarCRM Community here: https://community.sugarcrm.com/community/developer